# Removing the GTX 780 Ti power connector

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, computer-building

I'm removing an Nvidia GTX 780 Ti GPU from my case, but the power connector seems unusually firmly on place. Can the power connector potentially use some locking mechanism or should I be able to pull the cord out like a standard power plug?

---

https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-780-ti/specifications

> Supplementary Power Connectors | One 8-pin and one 6-pin

Comment: There could be a patch.  It really depends on your power supply.  Only you can determine if that’s the case nor not unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is often a pin on one side that keeps it in place, like the one in this random photo I picked up from a google search. You would have to either push it down on the far end of the connector, or pull it up where it's attached to the socket.

[image: gpu power cable connector]

Comment: Yes, there was a pin which only had to be pushed down apparently.