# How GPUs are attached to the motherboard?

Tags: graphics-card, computer-building

I'm removing a graphics card (GTX 780 Ti specifically) from a computer for the first time — after opening the frontal screws I'm unsure if the GPU is attached to the motherboard using some locking mechanism, [like the power connector was](https://superuser.com/questions/1453599/removing-the-gtx-780-ti-power-connector), as it doesn't feel safe to pull the card out by using force.

Comment: There may be a retaining screw to remove. Refer to the installation manual https://www.nvidia.com/content/geforce-gtx/GTX_760_User_Guide.pdf.

Comment: Make sure you un-clip the locking clip.

Comment: Not entirely related, but 780 Ti doesn't seem to have its own Nvidia manual. The 760's user guide looks applicable, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the motherboard there may be some kind of retaining clip holding the graphics card at the end of the PCIe slot towards the end closest to the front of your case.

It captures a retention finger on your graphics card.

[image]

The below picture shows two PCIe slots, the top one is broken while the lower has the retaining clip intact:

[image]

(Picture is from https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/761427-just-broke-my-pci-e-slots-lockretention-clip-or-whatever/)

Depending on your motherboard you may either need to push the clip to the side or push downwards on the clip.

Comment: In my case, I pushed down the retention level and gently pulled out the GPU.